# Finding supremum & infimum of a given set

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

> If exist, find, $\sup S,\inf S$\begin{equation}
>  S:=\left\{\left\lfloor\sqrt[|n|]{\frac{7}{3}}\right\rfloor\cdot
>  \frac{n^{2}-2 n-4}{n^{2}-n-6}: n \in
>  \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{-2,0,3\}\right\} \end{equation}

My attempt:
\begin{equation}f(n):=\left\lfloor\sqrt[|n|]{\frac{7}{3}}\right\rfloor\cdot \frac{n^{2}-2 n-4}{n^{2}-n-6}\end{equation}

$n=1, f(1)=\left\lfloor\frac{7}{3}\right\rfloor\cdot\frac{5}{6}=\frac{5}{3}$

$n=-1,f(-1)=\left\lfloor\frac{7}{3}\right\rfloor\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{2}$

$n=2,f(2)=\left\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{7}{3}}\right\rfloor\cdot\frac{1}{2}=1$
\begin{equation}\lim_{n\to -2}f(n)=\pm\infty=\lim_{{n\to 3}}f(n)\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=\left\lfloor\left(\frac{7}{3}\right)^{\left|\frac{1}{n}\right|}\right\rfloor\cdot\frac{1-\frac{2}{n}-\frac{4}{n^2}}{1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{6}{n^2}}=1\end{equation}
$$\implies\inf S=\frac{1}{2},\;\sup S=\frac{5}{3}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: You really can't the limit `n -> -2` or `n -> 3` since n is an integer. Also, are you saying that f(n) approaches 1 monotonically? If not, f(i) could be bigger than 5/3 or smaller than 1/2 for some value of i. Also, are you considering other negative values of n, such as n=-3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The points $n=0$, $n=-2$, and $n=3$ are excluded by definition. When $|n|\geq4$ the integer part of the square root is $1$ and the quotient is between $2/3 $ and $3/2$.

Besides the values you calculated, you have $f(-3)=11/6$. So the supremum is actually a maximum, and it is equals $11/6$. The infimum is a minimum and it equals $1/2$.